# TypeORM 0.3.6 errs processing raw SQL while running migrations

Tags: orm, typeorm

I am working with the below code, which worked fine with `typeorm` `0.2.x`. I am trying to upgrade my packages to `0.3.6`. It could be that the problem is somehow Mac-specific. Yet, I am not sure.

The script is below:

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';
export class CleanSlate1654889719399 implements MigrationInterface {
  name = 'CleanSlate1654889719399';

  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query('IF EXISTS DROP TABLE "onetime_viewer_token" CASCADE');
    ...
    await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "client_society_user" ("id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), "email" text NOT NULL, "tokenVersion" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', "created_at" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), "updated_at" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), "role" "public"."client_society_user_role_enum" NOT NULL, "isInternalAdmin" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false, "clientId" uuid, CONSTRAINT "PK_599c2dd9d3dc21c54f7df5d9c7e" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`);
    ...
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "client_user" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_eb3e491fab0ea63cd9f9ffba47d" FOREIGN KEY ("clientId") REFERENCES "client"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "discord_role" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_cc3204010e82bba2a8cdafb30fc"`);
    await queryRunner.query(`IF EXISTS DROP TABLE "onetime_transfer_token"`);
    ...
    await queryRunner.query(`IF EXISTS DROP TABLE "temp_token"`);
  }
}
```

When I am trying to run this migration with typeorm 0.3.x, it results in an error: `error: syntax error at or near "IF"`.

Is it still possible to use `QueryRunner` with raw SQL? `MigrationInterface` only supports `QueryRunner`...

Please advise.

Comment: I use typeorm 0.3.6 and I can confirm queryRunner.query works the same way it was. Maybe your database can't run this sql code.

Comment: Are you using a Mac, or something else? While it is perplexing to me, I believe that the issue * possibly * only affects macOS.

Comment: I am using Linux. I just wanted to answer part of your question that whether queryRunner still works as same in typeorm 0.3.x.

Comment: This is the question that I want to be answered. Apparently, you have Linux and it does not appear to have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below works fine [on both Mac and Linux] with `typeorm` 0.3.6:

```
await queryRunner.manager.query(...)
```